# Invalid CORS Request Error given by Nginx Reverse Proxy

Tags: nginx, cors

I am trying to configure my Nginx to support request from **localhost** to the backend API. I followed configurations from https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html. However, I am having a 403 problem, and the error message shown in the response is **Invalid CORS Request**.

Here is my Nginx configuration:

```
       location /v2/ {

                proxy_pass http://localhost:1051/v2/;
                 proxy_set_header Host      $host;
                 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

                 if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                        # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
                        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                        add_header 'Content-Type' 'application/json charset=UTF-8';
                        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
                         add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
                        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
                        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With' always;


                        return 204;
                }


                 add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;                            
                 add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
                        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
                        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With' always;
```

And here is the GET response header captured in Chrome network tab:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:
true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
*
Connection:
keep-alive
Date:
Thu, 01 Feb 2024 02:18:18 GMT
Server:
nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
Transfer-Encoding:
chunked
Vary:
Origin
Vary:
Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary:
Access-Control-Request-Headers
```

The Get request header:

```
Accept:
application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:
gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:
en,zh-CN;q=0.9,zh;q=0.8
Connection:
keep-alive
Content-Type:
application/json
Host:
101.34.67.120
Origin:
http://localhost
Referer:
http://localhost/
User-Agent:
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

The Preflight response header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:
true

Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
*
Access-Control-Max-Age:
1728000
Connection:
keep-alive
Content-Length:
0
Content-Type:
application/json charset=UTF-8
Date:
Thu, 01 Feb 2024 02:18:17 GMT
Server:
nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
```

The Preflight request header:

```
Accept:
*/*
Accept-Encoding:
gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:
en,zh-CN;q=0.9,zh;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:
content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:
GET
Connection:
keep-alive
Host:
101.34.67.120
Origin:
http://localhost
Referer:
http://localhost/
Sec-Fetch-Mode:
cors
User-Agent:
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

The Preflight did receive a 204 response, so I'm guessing the OPTION request works fine. But I am not sure what went wrong with my GET request and Nginx configs. Any help is appreciated.